# Wampserver2 + kohana 3.2 links issue

Tags: wamp, kohana-3.2

I am developing my first page in `Kohana 3.2` framework and I have a big problem. I have about 3 controllers:

1. default extends Template Controller,
2. home extends Default,
3. list extends Default.

Every controller has its own actions. I log in with home/login and redirect to list controller which opens action index to show some things in content of the template. The opened content has links to manage diffirent contents (like reprinting table with diffirent things in it). I want links to work like this controller/action but if one link is pressed, lets say, list/show, and i press again list/show (cause the menu is being shown all the time), it tries to enter list/show/list/show instead of just reopening the list/show. To sum up, it just adds pressed link to previous one, creating a mess. Does somebody know why is this happening? Apache's rewrite module is turned on.

Comment: Your href's probably look something like <a href="list/show"> . Change them to read <a href="/list/show">. The first slash means to start at the web root. Your version means to start at the current url and append whatever is in the href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always being href's with a slash and specify the path to the controller from the web root. In other words the link should be:

```
<a href="/list/show">
```

Comment: thx :) i've managed to come up with it by myself, but ur answer is good so i've accepted it :)